# Talking About Unfinished Projects

Tags: interviewing, resume, job-search, cover-letter

I held a part-time internship position for almost two years where I worked on everything from marketing to IT at a startup.

It was an amazing experience in learning how to use technology, such as Google Analytics, Google Ads, SEO, database design, and so much more. However, most of my work was just that, *learning*. Due to the nature of the company and other factors, I did not have much of a chance to actually run things like Google Ads, implement the database, etc.

As such, I do not have much concrete to show for it when it comes to finished products, but I have pages and pages of work, planning and drafts of the products. Thus, when applying for and interviewing for positions, how do I state in my application materials and interview that I did not get a chance to finish most of my projects?

For instance, if I am applying for positions in social media marketing, they may ask how many followers on Facebook I have when most of my work on that front was analyzing how to attain Facebook followers rather than implementing that work. Or they may check after the interview or after reading my cover letter.

However, perhaps I should not mention that I did not have a chance to complete the projects? Or should I tell them that if they ask a question like the aforementioned one?

*Edit- thank you for letting me know that I should focus moreso on what I learned. In that case, would it be alright to at least imply that I began my projects and learned about marketing in my resume and cover letter, as I do not want to give the impression that I fully completed my projects?

For instance, in my resume, I can write something like "*Began* developing technical projects ranging..." instead of "Developed technical projects..." as the latter may give the impression I completed everything. Similarly, I can write "*Learned* about online marketing principles and..." instead of "Designed marketing material...".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I include unfinished/cancelled projects to my portfolio?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12044/should-i-include-unfinished-cancelled-projects-to-my-portfolio)

Comment: @gnat I am a little confused as to how this is a duplicate. It is a different situation as this is an internship with different expectations from employers and I have the specific follow-up questions regarding my resume and interview and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an intern, especially part-time, hiring companies will understand that you didn't get to deliver finished products of your work into "production".  They are expecting that you got good exposure and a chance to work with those technologies.

You don't need to explicitly state that you didn't get to complete the projects.  Just be accurate in your representation of your experiences, you will only have concerns if you oversell what you did.

Answer (score 1):

You were a part time intern, so no one expects much from you, let alone finished products.

Just outline the areas you were involved with and go into more detail if asked. Target jobs where your training is an asset in terms of the job description.